# Plotting image of piecewise-defined transformation

Tags: list-manipulation, piecewise

I have a transformation $T : [-1,1]^2 \to [-1,1]^2$ that is piecewise defined in the following way:
\begin{align*}
T(x,y) &= \big(a(x-1)+1,\:\left(b-cx\right)(y-1)+1\big) \quad \textrm{if } y > 0, \\
T(x,y) &= \big(d(x+1)-1, \: \left(e-fx \right)(y+1)-1\big) \quad \textrm{if } y \leq 0
\end{align*}
for parameters $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb R$. I want to use Mathematica to help me visualize what the images of this function look like under repeated iteration.

I defined my function in Mathematica like so:

```
a=5/12; b=17/12; c=1/4; d=1/3; e=5/3; f=-1/6;
T[x_,y_] := {Piecewise[{{a(x-1)+1, y>0}, {d(x+1)-1, y<=0}}], 
Piecewise[{{(b-c*x)(y-1)+1, y>0}, {(e-f*x)(y+1)-1, y<=0}}]};
```

And then after writing `T[0.4,0.1]` and `T[0.2, -0.4]` to test the function, it returns as outputs `{0.75, -0.185}` and `{-0.6, 0.02}`. So this function appears to work.

Following in the footsteps of a (non-piecewise) example I was shown, I tried sketching the plot in the following way:

```
points=RandomReal[{-1,1},{5000,2}];
ListPlot[Map[T,points]]
```

which is written immediately below my lines in which I defined `T[x_,y_]`. I’m getting a sequence error message that all say:

```
Piecewise: The first argument {{-0.643301, False}, {0.422474}} of Piecewise is not a list of pairs.
```

with the numbers different between each error message. I wasn’t getting this error when I just directly evaluated `T[x,y]`, only when I tried plotting it/evaluating a set of data.

As an experiment, I tried running the following script:

```
a=5/12; b=17/12; c=1/4; d=1/3; e=5/3; f=-1/6;
T[x_,y_] := {Piecewise[{{a(x-1)+1, y>0}, {d(x+1)-1, y<=0}}], 
Piecewise[{{(b-c*x)(y-1)+1, y>0}, {(e-f*x)(y+1)-1, y<=0}}]};
F[x_,y_] := (e-f*x)(y+1)-1; (*the y-coordinate function for T when y<=0*)
points = {{0.4, 0.1}};
T[0.4, 0.1]
F[0.4, 0.1]
List[Map[T, points]]
```

This results in the following outputs and error message, in the following order:

```
Out[196]= {0.75, -0.185}
Out[197]= 0.906667

Piecewise: The first argument {{-0.185, True}, {0.906667}} of Piecewise is not a list of pairs.

Out[198[= {{{0.75, Piecewise[{{(b-c0.4)(0.1-1)+1, 0.1>0}, {(e-f0.4)(0.1+1)-1}}]}}}
```

So it appears that the problem is with the second `Piecewise` used in defining `T[x_,y_]`. It looks like it’s completely ignoring the `, y<=0` piece of it. Anyone have an idea of what’s going on here and how I can fix this?

Comment: It might simplify things a lot for you to define `T` so that it acts directly on points, e.g. `T[{x_, y_}] := (* your original definition *)`. That should let you avoid `Apply[]`, and also help with [your follow-up question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238931/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As used, Map will give T one List of two numbers as its argument, rather than two numbers. To do this as you intend, try this:

```
Map[Apply[T],points]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed it to look like. As a follow-up, I’m having trouble *iterating* this transformation. I’ve described what I’m trying to do at this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238931/plotting-iterates-of-a-piecewise-defined-map Any thoughts on what I should be trying to do here?