# Plotting iterates of a piecewise defined map

Tags: piecewise, iteration

This is a follow up question to the one I asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238927/plotting-image-of-piecewise-defined-transformation/238930#238930). I’ve succeeded in figuring out how to plot the first image of my piecewise defined transformation $T: [-1,1]^2 \to [-1,1]^2$, but now I want to plot *iterates* of this map. I’m trying to use `Nest[]` to do this, but I must not be doing it correctly. Here’s what I’m trying to do:

```
a=5/12; b=17/12; c=1/4; d=1/3; e=5/3; f=-1/6;
T[x_,y_] := {Piecewise[{{a(x-1)+1, y>0}, {d(x+1)-1, y<=0}}], Piecewise[{{(b-c*x)(y-1)+1, y>0}, {(e-f*x)(y+1)-1, y<=0}}]}; (*the function I’m trying to iterate*)
points = RandomReal[{-1,1},{10000,2}];
ListPlot[Map[Apply[T],points]]
```

This code plots the image of 10,000 random points transformed by my map $T$. But now I want to see where these points go, so I want to iterate the map; say I want to plot the image of $T(T(x))$. To do this, I tried:

```
a=5/12; b=17/12; c=1/4; d=1/3; e=5/3; f=-1/6;
T[x_,y_] := {Piecewise[{{a(x-1)+1, y>0}, {d(x+1)-1, y<=0}}], Piecewise[{{(b-c*x)(y-1)+1, y>0}, {(e-f*x)(y+1)-1, y<=0}}]}; (*the function I’m trying to iterate*)
points = RandomReal[{-1,1},{10000,2}];
ListPlot[Map[Apply[Nest[T, #, 2]&],points]]
```

This doesn’t give me any errors, but it just gives me axes without any points plotted. So I’m guessing it just doesn’t register that I’m trying to plug `points` into the function `Nest[T, #, 2]&`. Should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) and [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) allow you to achieve your aim.

For examples (with slight modification `T`):

```
a = 5/12; b = 17/12; c = 1/4; d = 1/3; e = 5/3; f = -1/6;
T[{x_, y_}] := {Piecewise[{{a (x - 1) + 1, y > 0}, {d (x + 1) - 1, 
     y <= 0}}], 
  Piecewise[{{(b - c*x) (y - 1) + 1, y > 0}, {(e - f*x) (y + 1) - 1, 
     y <= 0}}]};
points = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10000, 2}];
ListAnimate[
 ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True] & /@ 
  NestList[T /@ # &, points, 5]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I had in mind in my comment to the OP's previous question.

Comment: Apologies I had not seen previous question J M. I please feel free to link to comment or edit as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you, both of you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @DFord enjoy playing and working with Wolfram Language. There are many ways to achieve your goals.